# How to pass a variable to a method of an extended class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am extending the class `ClassVisitor` and overriding the method `visitMethod`. Then I extend the `MethodVisitor` and override the `visitMethodInsn`. When I override the `visitMethod` I create a new instance of the extended `MethodVisitor`.

Please see the code below to understand. Keep in mind knowledge of the ASM library is required in order to understand it properly.

GraphClass.java:

```
public class GraphClass extends ClassVisitor {
    public GraphClass() {
        super(ASM5);
    }

    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        System.out.println("testing " + name + desc);
        GraphMethod newVisitor = new GraphMethod();
        return newVisitor;
    }
}
```

GraphMethod.java:

```
public class GraphMethod extends MethodVisitor{
    public GraphMethod() {
        super(ASM5);
    }

    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, java.lang.String owner, java.lang.String name, java.lang.String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
        System.out.println(owner + name);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is pass the `name` variable from `visitMethod` to be printed along with the other variables in the `visitMethodInsn`.

I am new to Java, so any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; the name is passed to `visitMethodInsn` by the caller.

Comment: What codes calls the `visitMethodInsn()` method?

Comment: @DaveNewton it happens to be a different variable with just the same name
@AndrewS, this uses the ASM library, which makes use of the visitor pattern, so at some other part of the code there is an accept, which calls the `visitMethodInsn` for every method it finds

Comment: The code that calls `GraphClass.visitMethod` has variable that it passes to it as the `name` argument. This code then takes the returned `MethodVisitor` object and calls `visitMethodInsn` on it, passing it the same `name` argument as before. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @kampias It's still not clear what you want. `visitMethodInsn` gets the name of the method being called. Anything else would be non-sensical. What do you *want* to be passed to it?!

Comment: @DodgyCodeException the `newVisitor` will create a new instance of the `GraphMethod` but it does not pass the `name` variable. The `name` variable that is in the `visitMethodInsn` is a different one

Comment: I have rolled back someone's edit, in which they've removed the java-bytecode-asm tag. It seems to be a relevant tag. It may require knowledge of MethodVisitor to answer this question properly.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes it is relevant that is why i put it in first place, maybe i should add it as well in the question. Thank you

Comment: @kampias No, it doesn't pass the name of the method being visited--you already *know* that. It passes the name of the method being *called*, which is what `visitMethodInsn` handles. What *specific* issue are you having that the visitor pattern isn't fulfilling? This seems more like a basic algorithmic issue rather than anything Java- or ASM-specific. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DaveNewton, this line `System.out.println("testing " + name + desc);` prints the name of the method it visits, while the line `System.out.println(owner + name);` prints the names of the methods that this method calls.

Comment: @kampias Yes, that is the purpose of a visitor: to report on what is being visited. In the first case, the method, in the second case, a method call op. That, however, answers none of my questions.

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to make it print in this line `System.out.println(owner + name);` also the name of the method that calls the other methods.

Comment: @kampias What is preventing you from doing that? Print the method name in the method visitor, and the called method name in the method call visitor.

Comment: @DaveNewton i already do that, I wanted to make it print it all in a single line, in here `System.out.println(owner + name);`. But I could not figure out how.

Comment: @kampias Don't use `println` which ... prints a line? Or save off the info during visitation and print it later?

Comment: 1) change the `GraphMethod()` constructor to accept parameters, like the name of the method you’re visiting. Store the received values into fields of the class. 2) Change the `visitMethod` method of `GraphClass` to pass these values to the new object, i.e. `new GraphMethod(name)`. 3) Change the `visitMethodInsn` to use the fields created in step 1 in the print statement.

Comment: @Holger that seems to be what he asked for, why don't you submit this as an answer, with code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I will assume that you want to know which methods call by methods of the visited class, all right?

It takes solved easy by using tree-api of objectweb asm.

```java
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(bytesOfSomeClass);
//Used class node instead of visiter
ClasaNode cn = new ClassNode(<asm version>);

cr.accept(cn, 0);

//Iterate all methods of class
cn.methods.forEach( (MethodNode mn) -> {
    String callerName = mn.name;

    //Iterate all instructions of current method
    Stream.iterate(mn.instructions.getFirst(), AbstractInsnNode::getNext).limit(instructions.size())
        .filter(node -> node instanceof MethodInsnNode) //take only method calls
        .forEach(node -> {
            String calledName = ((MethodInsnNode) node).name;
            //Print results
            System.out.println(calledName + " is called by " + callerName);
         });
});
```